# razor engine for javascript files?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Is there any engine/tool/way to have razor inside JavaScript files? What I really need is something like this :

**StudentModel.Js file :**

```
@model Student

var x = {
   Title: '@Html.DisplayFor(o=>o.Title)',
   No:'@Model.No',
   GradeId: '@Html.IdFor(o=>o.Grade)'
};
```

Notes :

1. I don't want to use `cshtml` file with `<script>` inside it.
2. One important thing is intellisense.

Comment: RazorJS is the best solution for your situation

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this but there is a nuget package available for this -  [RazorJS](http://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorJS)

You can find the details

http://john.katsiotis.com/blog/razorjs---write-razor-inside-your-javascript-files

Comment: I checked it before. This component is just a html helper.

Comment: It is just an html helper,but helper will be rendered as script tag pointing your external js file as expected.

Comment: thanks but it is a nasty solution also have no intellisense & develop time validation inside the js file...and finally the RazorJs hasnt been maintained for 3 years as GrooV said

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Controller with an Action that returns a partial view. In the partial view you can write your javascript and be able to load it as an external javascript file by `<script src="http://url/JavascriptControllerName/Action"></script>`

Or use the RazorJS nuget package but that hasnt been maintained for 3 years